# How to customize Gmap?

Tags: javascript, css, customizing

I am using Gmap on my website and I notice that i sets position:relative on the #map. How do I change this? I don't want any positioning on the #map div. I looked over the gmaps.js and couldn't find it. 
Another problem is how to make the gmap load in satellite mode by default instead of map?
Also can I get rid of all the other things I get by default - zoomer, arrows, text at the bottom right etc. I just want a clean map in satellite mode.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible in gmaps from looking at the docs but it __is__ possible with the actual google maps api
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For best results, you should create one question per ... question and give it a meaningful title. For example, one question "How to avoid position:relative in gmap" an another one "How to make gmap load in satellite mode by default". In this way, anybody having one of these problems in the future will quickly find your post and benefit from the answer. It is also recommended to include meaningful tags (is this question about Google Maps or specifically about the jQuery gmap plugin?).